# iOS Retain multiple variables on a view after leaving then returning to it

Tags: ios, objective-c

I feel ignorant for asking this because I know it's simple. Goal: Retain a variable on a view after leave then returning to it.

For instance: Let's say we have **MainView**, **CategoryView** and (drumroll) **ProjectView**

Application opens to **MainView** it displays a table - user selects they want to pick a category. This segue's them to **CategoryView**. Once a selection is made I send the chosen category back to **MainView**. via

```
    -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

No problem here. MainView receives variable and displays the chosen category as subtext in the 'Category' section. Next the user wants to pick a project name (this is also a predefined list) They select the item and I send the variable back the MainView.

-- Now can somebody explain to me (gently) why when I return to the main view the NSString variable that was previously holding the 'chosen' category is now null?

So my NSString selectedProject is not being retained correct? What is the correct implementation I should be doing here? Or what am I missing? I'm really trying to understand whats going on so anything would be a great help.

**MainView Interface**

```
    @interface MainViewController : UIViewController {
        NSString *selectedProjectName;
        NSString *selectedCategory;
    }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *selectedProjectName;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *selectedCategory;

    @end
```

**MainView Implementation**

```
    @implementation MainViewController
    @synthesize selectedCategory, selectedProjectName;
```

and if you need it..
**ProjectView Implementation**

```
  -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"masterSegue"]) {
    MainViewController *vc = (MainViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];

    LogValues *lv = [LogValues alloc];

    lv.project = @"Test Project Name";
    vc.selectedProjectName = lv.project;
    } 
    }
```

Comment: Probably because you're not "returning" to the main view, you're probably creating a new instance. How do you go "back" to the main view (what type of segue)?

Comment: returning back I have the segue set to modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, your problem is that you're not returning to the same instance. You've missed one very very important thing about segues -- they ALWAYS instantiate new view controllers. So, when you use a modal segue to go "back" to the main view controller, you're just creating a new instance of that controller. You should never go backwards (to earlier controllers) in a storyboard using anything other than an unwind segue. Unwinds are the exception to the rule about segues always creating new instances.

So, you have 2 choices. You can either use an unwind segue, which is nice, because you can still implement prepareForSegue to send data back to the destination controller, or you can not use a segue at all, and use dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: to go back, and use a delegate to send back the data.

Comment: If you don't know how to make an unwind segue, see my answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16160239/1285133

Comment: That's great man, appreciate the explanation. I'll look into using unwinds, I haven't heard of those yet, somehow.

Answer (score -1):

So of course immediately after posting I see a thread in the side that I believe helps. The solution was to store the values in the *AppDelegate* which is working fine.

I feel however there are other ways to achieve the same result without having to rely on the AppDelegate and would love to hear other solutions.

Comment: So if this is a bad way to go, even though it works fine - Would you mind giving an explanation as to the more proper way. It's a small inhouse application only 8 variables to store so I dont see the harm doing it this way. Just trying to learn the best.