# How to move back to the root view controller in storyboard?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa, uistoryboard

What I want to do seems pretty simple, but I can't find any answers on the web. I have the login screen as the root view controller and then tab bar controller and in every tab I have a navigation controller.

I have used storyboard and the hierarchy is described below,

```
Root VC
    |
     --- tabbar controller
          |
           ---Navigation Controller
                |
                 --- VC1
```

Requirement is to navigate back to the root view controller from VC1. How can we achieve this?

Comment: You should use an unwind segue to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @rdelmar, I agreed to your solution. But the issue i am facing now is, i am unable to connect the button outlet to exit button of storyboard to unwind it. It was not accessible, it seems. Can you please help me on this.

Comment: Look at my answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158586/app-running-slow-after-loading-viewcontroller-then-unload-about-15-20-times/16160239#16160239), and see if that's how you're trying to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the resolution to the issues using the "Unwind Segues".

Step 1) The bare minimum you need is to subclass the view controller for your destination view (aka, a view that has popped up previously in navigation and you want to unwind to it) and add a method like this to it (the method name can be anything you want, but it should be unique because all unwind segues in your entire app are listed together):

```
- (IBAction)unwindToViewControllerNameHere:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
//nothing goes here
}
```

Step 2) Now, in your source view (aka, the view that you want to unwind from) you simply drag a segue from your button or whatever down to the little green "EXIT" icon at the bottom of your source view. There should now be an option to connect to "- unwindToViewControllerNameHere"

That's it, your segue will unwind when your button is tapped. And we can move to any view controller we want and rest of the view controllers will be released.

Answer (score 2):

If you have controllers hierarchy like

--- Navigation Controller -- | Root VC | --- tabbar controller | --- Navigation Controller -- | --- VC1

and there is a `UIButton` on VC1, so on click of that you want to move to root viewcontroller (Root VC) then use :

```
-(void)moveToRootViewController {

    //Move to root viewController
    UINavigationController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainnav"];

    self.view.window.rootViewController = controller;

 }
```

here `mainnav` is storyboard identifier of root viewcontroller Navigation Controller.

[image: ViewControllers hierarchy]

According to picture white colour viewcontroller is a root viewcontroller and tabBarController have 2 tabs with navigation controller and if you want to move to root viewcontroller from second tab viewcontroller `UIButton`(black colour) click then use the above code.

If you have  hierarchy like
--- Navigation Controller -- | Root VC | --- VC1---- |--- VC2---- |

and want to move to root viewcontroller (Root VC) from VC1 or from VC2 then use :

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
- (void) forRootViewCon {
    UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController*) self.view.window.rootViewController;
    UIViewController *root = [nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    [root performSelector:@selector(returnToRoot)];
}
```

Call method name is **returnToRoot**

```
- (void)returnToRoot {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

**OR**

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough.

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should enable the Root VC in the navigation controller :

--- Navigation Controller -- |  Root VC | --- tabbar controller | --- VC1

And then call

```
[navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

EDIT :
I guess you have issues including a tabBar controller inside a navigation controller ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i want to know about the navigation in tabbar controller. I think its not good to have the hierarchy like NavigationController -> tabbar controller -> Navigation controller. Apple will not suggest this.

Comment: I have a Root VC in the navigation controller, but I hide it. How to go to root view?